# How to programmatically concatenate two aac files

Tags: iphone, ruby, audio, ffmpeg

Does any one know how concatenate two aac audio files into one.  I can do this with mp3 using ffmpeg but no luck with files with an m4a extension.

I tried the following with no luck:`ffmpeg -i concat:"file1.m4a\|file2.m4a" -c copy output.m4a'`

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/64389/66282

Comment: @satuon decompressing and then compressing will deminish quality.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about that, but then, I'm not one of those people who can tell the difference between a WAV file and a 128k mp3 :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use cat:

```
cat file1.m4a file2.m4a >output.m4a
```

Comment: Hi, I wonder why does this work? IMHO there should be some headers and footers inside each file? Thanks!